Simple JWT says sometimes "Token is invalid or expired" and sometimes gives correct output
I have a Django REST backend configured Simple-JWT solution. About 2/3 of the requests return #
{"detail":"Given token not valid for any token type","code":"token_not_valid","messages":[{"token_class":"AccessToken","token_type":"access","message":"Token is invalid or expired"}]}

and the rest returns the normal outcome.
e.g. these curls I did directly one after another and the first fails while the second (same access token) returns a right value:
C:\Users\user>curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzE4NDAxMzc5LCJpYXQiOjE3MTg0MDA0NzksImp0aSI6Ijc2YTcwZjU0OTA2ZjQwOTNhYzc2MzRhYTFmNmJjNTlhIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6Miwicm9sZSI6MSwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOm51bGwsImZ1bGxfYWNjZXNzX2dyb3VwIjp0cnVlfQ.p8BRy95SSiBmqeSjmCkAHFddRjKmzEOowP2RT34Jp6Y" http://3.71.19.16/accounts/courses/
{"detail":"Given token not valid for any token type","code":"token_not_valid","messages":[{"token_class":"AccessToken","token_type":"access","message":"Token is invalid or expired"}]}

C:\Users\user>curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzE4NDAxMzc5LCJpYXQiOjE3MTg0MDA0NzksImp0aSI6Ijc2YTcwZjU0OTA2ZjQwOTNhYzc2MzRhYTFmNmJjNTlhIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6Miwicm9sZSI6MSwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOm51bGwsImZ1bGxfYWNjZXNzX2dyb3VwIjp0cnVlfQ.p8BRy95SSiBmqeSjmCkAHFddRjKmzEOowP2RT34Jp6Y" http://3.71.19.16/accounts/courses/
[{"id":1,"name":"Testkurs 1","language":1,"teacher":2,"grade":5,"start_date":null,"study_started":false,"activate_final_test":false,"number_of_students":90,"created_at":"2024-06-11T14:13:15.498484Z","scheduled_study_start":null,"scheduled_final_test":null,"demo":false},{"id":2,"name":"Testkurs 2","language":1,"teacher":2,"grade":5,"start_date":null,"study_started":false,"activate_final_test":false,"number_of_students":70,"created_at":"2024-06-11T14:17:58.503959Z","scheduled_study_start":null,"scheduled_final_test":null,"demo":false},{"id":3,"name":"Test","language":1,"teacher":2,"grade":5,"start_date":null,"study_started":false,"activate_final_test":false,"number_of_students":0,"created_at":"2024-06-13T22:35:51.513376Z","scheduled_study_start":null,"scheduled_final_test":null,"demo":false}]

This is my Django Simple JWT-Setup:
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=15),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=90),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 60,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=15),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}

and my nginx config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1; # change with url

    location = /favicon.ico { 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/USER/static/;
    }

    location / {
        # Add the necessary headers
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}

It works perfectly fine when I run the server on localhost on my home computer but has troubles on AWS lightsail machine with nearly the same setup. I have Cloudflare and Nginx only on the machine.
Do anyone know what the issue might be? I tried fixing it for nearly 8 hours now...

I just found the solution. The 1/3 correct percentage made me aware, that I also use gunicorn with exactly 3 workers. I realized, that I used Django's get_random_secret_key function which generates a random key for each gunicorn worker and therefore they often did NOT match.
